# How to detect that you are running in embedded IE browser?

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

.NET has the IE wrapper, that lets you put a web browser in your app easily

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx

Our web page needs to detect that it is running in an IE embedded in an app (because IE behaves differently when embedded).

How can we do this?

(Aside: Even if IE 10 or 11 is on the system, when IE is embedded, when we do the standard test in js for browser version, it seems we always detect IE as v7, even though IE 10 or such is on the system.)

Comment: Welcome to a world of pain. The webbrowser control is problematic at best.  I don't have an answer to your question.  Just a comment.

Comment: You can force the emulation to a newer ID version using the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION xx.exe to 11000  where xx.exe is the name of you exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is our answer:

If the browser detected is IE7, then assume it is embedded.

This is an imperfect answer, but in our situation it is the most appropriate path forward, as there seems to be no other way.